# Rendering OSM XML file with Mapnik and street names

Tags: mapnik

I am rendering OSM XML tiles using [Mapnik](http://mapnik.org/), but when I increase my font size for road names, some roads appear to show text twice in a row.

Here is an image of what I mean:

[image: street names]

Note the unwanted repetition of:

- Stirling Street
- Atkins Street (on the right)

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but I think you need "text-spacing"(Distance between repeated text labels on a line (aka. label-spacing)).

Usefull link - https://github.com/mapbox/carto/blob/master/docs/latest.md

Answer (score 0):

In case you are working directly with Mapnik XML to style your layers, the property you are looking for is `repeat-distance` in your `TextSymbolizer`. This property is defined as (in pixels):

> Minimum distance between repeated labels such as street names or shield symbols (works across features)

See reference here: https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/TextSymbolizer